# android Camera flash don't work

Tags: android, camera

The camera flickered and disappeared ,Are there any compatible measures?

```
  Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(0); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        Camera.Parameters p = c.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        c.setParameters(p);
        c.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        Log.e(TAG,"exception e"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Check for permission to flash

```
     c = Camera.open();  
     Camera.Parameters params=null;  
     params= c.getParameters();  
     List<String> supportedFlashModes = sParams.getSupportedFlashModes();

                if (supportedFlashModes != null) {

                    if (supportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
                        sParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    } else if (supportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
                        sParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                    } else c = null;


                } else Log.d(TAG, "Camera is null.");


                if (c != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Flash disponibile (" + sParams.getFlashMode() + ")");
                    c.setParameters(sParams);

                    c.autoFocus(null);

                }
```

2.Some special cases of using SurfaceView:

```
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  

  if(mCamera!=null){
            mCamera.release();
        }
        mCamera=Camera.open();

        mCamera.setParameters(PerviousParams);
        mCamera.startPreview();
}
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

  if(mCamera!=null){
            mCamera.release();
        }
        mCamera=Camera.open();

        mCamera.setParameters(PerviousParams);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
```